# Exim Forward Email to Remote Server

Tags: linux, debian, email, exim

I am setting up a mail server with exim, spamassassin, clamav ..etc on Linux Debian so that it can act as an email spam-filtering gateway for inbound email. I will have 4 domains that will go through this gateway, and the filtered-emails will need to be forwarded respectively.

For example: all emails sent to any mailbox under @example.com will forward to mail.example.com; and all emails to any mailbox under @example.net will forward to mail.example.net.

How do I configure Exim to achieve this, or is it not possible for multiple domains/destinations?

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure `rewrite` section of the `exim`'s config:

```
begin rewrite
*@example.com  $local_part@mail.example.com       Eh
*@example.net  $local_part@mail.example.net       Eh
```

All messages will be rewritten just immediately after receiving and processed through ACLs and routers in the rewritten form. So you have to set up `relay_to_domains` variable to ensure it contains `mail.example.com` and `mail.example.net`.

The other approach is to create the routers that use `manualroute` directive to forward all the messages whos `domains = example.com` to the corresponding MX that should be configured accordingly:

```
begin routers
. . . . . .
forwarder1:
  driver = manualroute
  domains = example.com
  route_data = mail.example.com
```

Make sure that forwarders should be placed above the normal message processing.

Also you can do a flexible single router that uses lookups to find the proper `route_data` correspondingly to the destination domain. Further reading can be found in the `exim` specification.